# Azure Services Authentication Extension default tenant / subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I'm doing local azure function development for an MSI-enabled application using Visual Studio 2017 v15.6.2 with the [Azure Services Authentication Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension) installed. The identity I have to work with in the target subscription has access to multiple tenants and subscriptions within those tenants.

Before I installed the add-in I was able to use the Azure CLI to set the default subscription/tenant using `az account set -subscripton TARGET-SUB-NAME`. `az account show` confirmed that I had selected the correct subscription and everything worked well.

Since installing the VS extension I can no longer access the resources in the target subscription because the extension has no way to select the default tenant/subscription combo. The CLI still shows the target subscription, but JWTs that are generated by `GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");` calls show that the tokens are being requested with the identity's default subscription (`tid` in the token).

Is there a way to set the default subscription for the extension or otherwise get around this blocker?

Comment: Are you using V2.0 extension for Visual studio code? If yes, you will need to set the azure.tenantId setting. This setting being entered using the File -> Preferences -> User Settings feature. Refer: [Azure Tools for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradygaster.azuretoolsforvscode)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I'm using VS 2017

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-visual-studio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get around the shortcomings of the Azure Service Authentication feature (which is no longer an extension, but built into VS.net 2017) by following the [instructions on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support).

Specifically, I used the connection string `RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli` in the environmental variable `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` and was able to return control to the CLI.