# How can I remove Azure Services Authentication Extension from VS 2017?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I'm [having problems with the App Service Extension in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331395/azure-services-authentication-extension-default-tenant-subscription) and would like to remove it so I can auth during development using the azure CLI instead, but I can't figure out how to remove the extension. It doesn't appear in Tools -> Extensions and Updates or Add/Remove programs. I'd rather not reinstall VS.net. Anyone know?

Comment: Tried both 'Azure Service' and 'App Service' but don't see anything that matches or resembles the name of the add-in. Couple of Roslyns, logic and function app, snapshot debugger, and razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this extension is built into versions of VS 2017 greater than (I believe) 15.6. No way to remove it.